# Default parseInt radix to 10

Tags: javascript

One of the bad parts of JavaScript is that if you use parseInt with something that begins with 0, then it could see the number as a octal.

```
i = parseInt(014); // Answer: 12
```

Q: How can I redefine parseInt so that it defaults to radix 10?  I'm assuming you would use the prototype method.

Edit:

Maybe I should do this:

```
$.fn.extend({
    parseInt:function(X) {
        return parseInt(X,10);
    }
});
```

Comment: Maybe in the long tradition of jQuery, there should be a $.parseInt().

Comment: I assume you mean `parseInt('014')`, not `parseInt(014)`.

Comment: `014` is an octal number. `0x14` is hex.

Comment: Thats not Hexa decimal. Its octal. So `014=10x8+4=12`

Comment: How about just `var myParseInt = function (num, radix) { return parseInt(num, radix || 10); };` ? Unsure what will happen if you change `myParseInt` to `parseInt`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you store a reference to the original `parseInt` function, you can overwrite it with your own implementation;

```
(function () {
    var origParseInt = window.parseInt;

    window.parseInt = function (val, radix) {
        if (arguments.length === 1) {
            radix = 10;
        }

        return origParseInt.call(this, val, radix);
    };

}());
```

However, I **strongly** recommend you **don't** do this. It is bad practise to modify objects you don't own, *let alone* change the signature of objects you don't own. What happens if other code you have **relies** on octal being the default?

It will be **much** better to define your own function as a shortcut;

```
function myParseInt(val, radix) {
    if (typeof radix === "undefined") {
        radix = 10;
    }

    return parseInt(val, radix);
}
```

Comment: Crockford says to never use double equal signs.  Should it be "radix === undefined"?

Comment: Since you're changing radix in the above function, would that change it in calling routine as well, or are variables passed as values?

Comment: @Pedro: Crockford is a pedantic %*£^. You can use a `===` to be more precise, but it'll work fine with `==`.

Comment: @Pedro: They act *like* they're being passed values. *Unless you pass an array or object, in which case they act like reference*.

Answer (score 7):

### Introduction

First off, the `parseInt` method assumes the following<sup>[source](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp)</sup>:

- if it starts with 0x - then it is hex.
- if it starts with 0 - then it is octal
- else it is decimal

So you could go with the solution, never start with 0 ;)

### Solution

With ECMA-262 (aka EcmaScript 5, aka JavaScript version 5) one of the new features is strict mode which you turn on with `"use strict"`

When you opt-in to strict mode the rules change<sup>[source](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/es5-chapter-2-strict-mode/#octal-extension-for-literals)</sup>:

- if it starts with 0x - then it is hex
- else it is decimal

The only way to get octal then is to set the radix parameter to 8.

### Problem

At the time of writing the support for ECMAScript 5 isn't consistent across all browsers and so some browsers do not support it at all, which means the solution isn't useful to them. Other browsers implementations are broken, so even though the proclaim it supports it, they do not.

The below image is of IE 10 release preview versus Chrome 19 - where IE runs it correctly but Chrome doesn't.

[image: Chrome 19 versus IE 10 Release Preview]

The easy way to check your browser is to go to: http://repl.it/CZO#
You should get 10, 10, 8, 10, 16 as the result there, if so great - if not your browser is broken :(

Comment: From the ECMA-262 link you gave: "Notice again, that new parseInt algorithm is applied regardless strict mode and regardless numeric grammar extension:". `parseInt` has changed in ES5, **even without strict mode**.

Answer (score 5):

I assume you mean `parseInt('014')`, not `parseInt(014)`.

If you really want to replace `parseInt` with your own function (*I strongly discourage this*), I guess you could do it with something like:

```
(function(_parseInt)
{   
    parseInt = function(string, radix)
    {    return _parseInt(string, radix || 10);
    };

})(parseInt);
```

Comment: No, I meant parseInt(014).  The solution is to "use strict"

Answer (score 4):

I would personally use a partial function application pattern for this. Something like:

```
function createIntParser(radix) {
    return function(val) {
        return window.parseInt(val, radix);        
    }
}

decimalParseInt = createIntParser(10);

alert(decimalParseInt("010"));​
```

but i like to be explicit.

Comment: Hmmm.. I wonder if I could name decimalParseInt to simple be: Int.  Or would Int be considered a no-no?

Comment: Yeah, it looks like Int is a reserved word brought over from Java (according to the definitive guide to JavaScript).

Comment: Table 2-2 Words reserved for ECMA extensions

Comment: This post could be edited as it is no longer appropriate to assume there is a browser for javascript.

Answer (score 2):

```
i = parseInt('014',10);
```

Anyway, when you say `014`, it already means the number 12, so `parseInt` can do nothing useful with it.

```js
console.log('014===12:', 014===12);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a second param for `parseInt()`:

`parseInt(x, [radix])`

http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/globalfunctions.shtml

Comment: Thanks Yuri!  I didn't make it obvious in my question that I already knew that, so I appreciate you saying it.