# sum values of a javascript array?

Tags: jquery, arrays, sum

I have looked at a lot of different varriations of this question but i cant seem to find one that is particular to what i am doing.

I have input fields that are dynamicaly created by a php/mysql query. the values are numbers and they share a common class

```
<?php
   foreach ($garment_sizes as $key =>$value){echo '<input type="number" class="size_select" name="'.$value.'" onchange="qty_update()"/><label class="size_label">'. strtoupper($value).'</label>';
   }
?>
```

Resulting HTML:

```
<input type="number" class="size_select" name="s" onchange="qty_update()"/>
<label class="size_label">S</label>
<input type="number" class="size_select" name="m" onchange="qty_update()"/>
<label class="size_label">M</label> <!-- etc -->
```

I want to create a function to sum all the fields with this class "size_select"

```
function qty_update(){
    var values = $('.size_select').serializeArray();
    //having trouble writing the loop here to sum the array..
}
```

Comment: Just curious, why do you need to serialize? JSON?

Comment: well, i have been trying to learn jquery this past couple of months, so it is the first place i go when i want to do something new. I am open to a better solution.

Comment: Why do you need to serialize?

Comment: I thought it was the easiest way to pack an unknown number of input fields into an array based on a common class...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To sum all fields that match a particular selector, you can do this:

```
var total = 0;
$('.size_select').each(function() {
    total += parseInt($(this).val(), 10) || 0;
});

// the variable total holds the sum here
```

In function form:

```
function sumSizes() {
    var total = 0;
    $('.size_select').each(function() {
        total += parseInt($(this).val(), 10) || 0;
    });
    return(total);
}
```

Comment: Wow, that's pretty much exactly what I posted.

Comment: Thanks jfriend00. The function form works. can you help me understand ,10 || 0? What is this doing?

Comment: @DanielHunter - See these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9380039/default-parseint-radix-to-10 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/850341/workarounds-for-javascript-parseint-octal-bug

Comment: @DanielHunter - the `parseInt() || 0` is adding to `total` either the result of `parseInt()` or, if that's not a truthy value (like if the field is blank or doesn't contain a number), then it's adding 0.  It's just a shortcut for testing the result of `parseInt()` with `if (!isNaN(x))` that saves a lot of lines of code because you don't need the if statement. The `10` is the radix argument to `parseInt()` and should almost always be used because without it, `parseInt()` can guess the radix based on the content.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one quick approach. Note that, if you're using jQuery, you should generally use jQuery to assign event handlers, as it's more flexible than doing so directly in the HTML markup:

```
$('input.size_select').change(function() {
    var sum = 0;
    $('input.size_select').each(function() {
         sum += parseInt($(this).val()) || 0
    });
    console.log(sum);
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't `parseInt($(this).val)` be `parseInt( $(this).val() )`?