# Javascript operand

Tags: javascript, html

I have this javascript code when i use this function on a button it just sticks the two input texts but i want to add them for example:
the result is : 2+3=23
but i want 2+3=5
where is my problem?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Add()
    {
        var a;
        var b;
        var c;
        a = document.getElementById('Text1').value;
        b = document.getElementById('Text2').value;
        c = a - b;
        document.getElementById('Text3').value = c;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: `+` is concatenation for strings.

Comment: so how can i add two numbers?

Comment: You need to make numbers out of them rather than a String.

Comment: use parseInt(number1) + parseInt(number2)

Comment: Turn strings into numbers (the easiest way to do this with unary plus).

Comment: Way to go scarying the new guy who wants to learn downvoters...

Comment: The MSDN has some useful documentation about what the plus operator does in JavaScript: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/wwfws59w(v=vs.94).aspx

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: the questioner's been here for more than two years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `parseInt`:

```
var myNum = parseInt(a, 10) + parseInt(b, 10);
```

You should always call this with its radix argument (`, 10`). [Here's why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9380039/default-parseint-radix-to-10).

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) also lists it as a required parameter.

Comment: Do we -1 for you assuming the values are integers or do we comment?

Comment: @NigelAngel Don't get so touchy. The OP said they *are* integers anyway: `the result is : 2+3=23 but i want 2+3=5`

Comment: only in the example they gave.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that `document.getElementById('Text1').value` returns string value, so adding one string to another does string concatenation.

You should cast your values to numbers with [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) or [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat), e.g.:

```
a = document.getElementById('Text1').value;  // "2"
b = document.getElementById('Text2').value;  // "3"
c = parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b);           //  5
```

**USEFUL:** https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/90203/why-is-so-bad-for-concatenation

Answer (score 2):

Using the infix operator is shorter:

```
a = +document.getElementById('Text1').value;
b = +document.getElementById('Text2').value;
```

Answer (score 1):

`+` adds numbers and concats strings. Since you haven't said that your numbers are integers, using `parseInt()` may not be correct, you should use `parseFloat()` to convert the strings to floats.

```
a = parseFloat(document.getElementById('Text1').value);
b = parseFloat(document.getElementById('Text2').value);
```

[parseFloat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)

Answer (score 1):

It's concatenating the strings `2` and `3`.

```
> '2' + '3'
"23"
> 2 + 3
5
```

You can get by this by using `parseInt(numberVariable, 10)`:

```
> parseInt('2', 10) + parseInt('3', 10)
5
```

If you use decimal numbers, you can use `parseFloat(numberVariable)`.

```
> parseFloat('2') + parseFloat('3')
5
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to convert them to integers, and then add them up:

```
a = parseInt(document.getElementById('Text1').value, 10);
b = parseInt(document.getElementById('Text2').value, 10);
```

If the value of the text boxes aren't integers, but floats, then use `parseFloat`.

Comment: -1 for lack of a radix parameter. It should **always** be set.

Comment: +1, lack of radix parameter warrants a comment, not a -1.

Comment: @DannyBeckett: I added a radix parameter.

Comment: @NigelAngel It's the source of some really odd bugs. It warrants a -1 until the OP fixes it. Then it should be reversed. Now, I can't undo it, because you've +1'd it.

Comment: @NigelAngel: no need for the +1, just don't vote.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy I meant I can't undo, because now I'm undoing Nigel's vote that was to counteract mine. This whole thing's f'ing hilarious.

Comment: @DannyBeckett: generally I don't do "top up" votes just because it didn't deserve a downvote from someone else -- votes should be of your own opinion, regardless of what someone else thinks of it.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy That's exactly my point too